# Is There a way to use dynamic_cast When Casting to a Child?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, downcast

Say that I that I have these classes:

```
struct Parent {};
struct Child : public Parent {
    void func() {}
};
```

Now say that I wanted to create a function like this:

```
void foo(Parent* arg) {
    auto child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(arg);

    if(child != nullptr) child->func();
}
```

But obviously that will obviously give me the error:

> `dynamic_cast`: `Parent` is not a polymorphic type

So I can't do the `dynamic_cast` step, is there a way that I can validate that `arg` is in fact a `Child*` at run-time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. The information you can get about an object at runtime is achieved using the `RTTI` (`Run Time Type Information`). The `RTTI` of an object is stored within the virtual table of it's class.

Each object of a polymorphic class (i.e. a class which has one or more virtual functions, or a class which is derived from a polymorphic class) contains a `vptr`, which is a pointer to the virtual table of the corresponding class. An object of a non-polymorphic type has no `vptr` and there is not a virtual table for its class. Therefore you cannot use `dynamic_cast` on non-polymorphic types.

So, as @lorro said, you should add a virtual function to `Parent`, and the simplest option is adding a virtual destructor (which you should do anyway):

```
struct Parent {
    virtual ~Parent() {} 
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Give your `Parent` class a virtual function. Destructor comes into mind, for several reasons (like deleting child via base ptr, etc.).